# Password VBA vs. manually typed do not match

Tags: vba, excel

I have an ActiveX Toggle button in a protected sheet with password.
When I want to trigger an action, it does need to unprotect the sheet.

What happens is that the same password that has been inserted manually by right-clicking on the sheet name>>Protect Sheet... does not work if I use VBA.
The same is true the other way round: if I protect the sheet using VBA, then I am not able to unprotect it manually by right-clicking on the sheet name>>Protect Sheet...

Here is my code:

```
Private Sub ToggleButton1_Click()
On Error GoTo Error_handler

psw = InputBox("please enter the password")

If ToggleButton1.Value = False Then
    Worksheets("Multiregional").Unprotect Password = psw
        ToggleButton1.BackColor = vbGreen
        Call hide_columns 'this filters row and hides a few columns
    Worksheets("Multiregional").Protect Password = psw, DrawingObjects:=False, Contents:=True, Scenarios:=False, AllowFormattingColumns:=False, AllowFormattingRows:=False, _
        AllowSorting:=True, AllowFiltering:=True, AllowUsingPivotTables:=True

ElseIf ToggleButton1.Value = True Then
    Worksheets("Multiregional").Unprotect Password = psw
    ToggleButton1.BackColor = RGB(204, 204, 204)
    Call show_everything 'this unhide and unfilter everything
    Worksheets("Multiregional").Protect Password = psw, DrawingObjects:=False, Contents:=True, Scenarios:=False, AllowFormattingColumns:=False, AllowFormattingRows:=False, _
        AllowSorting:=True, AllowFiltering:=True, AllowUsingPivotTables:=True
End If

Exit Sub
Error_handler:
MsgBox Err.Description

End Sub
```

I tried these two ways to insert a password, but NONE of the two works;

- using inputbox (as above: `psw = InputBox("please enter the password")` and then `Worksheets("Multiregional").Unprotect Password = psw`
- typing the psw in the code `Worksheets("Multiregional").Unprotect Password = "xyz"`

EDIT:

What does not work is unprotecting the sheet in a **different method than the one used to protect it** (and the other way round), because for some reason the same psw entered via VBA *or* manually seems to be not recognised as the same string by Excel. This results in the fact that:
1)  If I set the psw via VBA, I cannot manually unprotect the sheet and, conversely,
2)  if I set up the psw manually, I cannot use the macro.
In both cases the error message is that the psw is not correct.

Do you have a solution or experienced the same problem before?

Thanks to all of you in advance for your kind support!

Answer (score 2):

Start from something really small. E.g. try this:

```
Public Sub TestMe()

    Dim psw As String
    psw = InputBox("please enter the password")
    MsgBox psw   'to see what you have entered

    If psw = "xyz" Then
        Worksheets(1).Unprotect "xyz1"
    Else
        Worksheets(1).Protect "xyz1"
    End If

End Sub
```

If the password is `xyz` then unprotect, otherwise - protect. Once this works, you can continue building further logic.

Comment: Thanks Vityata for your reply, but I think I did not explain well what the issues is. The macro above works with no problem, i.e. it performs the hiding/unhiding of columns.
I added an explanation to the original post, it may clarify the problem.

Comment: @Ema - I see. What would happen if you use only the code in my answer. Would you be able to protect/unprotect the sheet manually after this? Are you using multiple keyboard layouts, except for English?

Comment: it works in the sense that I can protect/unprotect the sheet both manually and via VBA - although this is not linked to a click event. But I also noticed that it protects the sheet with any psw other than "xyz", that may lead the user to not being able to work on the sheet anymore...

Comment: @Ema - you can always play a bit around. Now, if the password is not `xyz` but anything else, it is set to `xyz1`. And the user needs to give `xyz` manually. In general, it depends on the business logic you want to follow.

Comment: @Vitayta, problem solved: I copied all the values and re-written the same code, it works perfectly know and has no issue when protecting/unprotecting both manually or via VBA. Maybe because the file was produced in older versions of Excel?

Comment: @Ema - congrats. Concerning the file, anything is possible.

Answer (score 0):

I just had this same problem, and thought I'd share what I found.  The problem is, colons should be used when protecting/unprotecting sheets via script:

```
Worksheets("Multiregional").Protect Password = psw
Worksheets("Multiregional").Unprotect Password = psw
```

should be

```
Worksheets("Multiregional").Protect Password := psw
Worksheets("Multiregional").Unprotect Password := psw
```